# php contact form not working with some email addresses?

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a really simple php contact form on one of my sites, the problem is that it won't work when sending emails to some addresses.

It works fine sending to my gmail address, but it doesn't work with iCloud (@me.com) addresses or other domain specific emails that I have set up.

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("myemailaddress@me.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

If it didn't work at all I'd know there was a syntax error, but I get the 'Email Sent!' confirmation.

Comment: How can you tell that "it doesn't work with iCloud" ? Have you checked the spam folder ?

Comment: better check your `mail()` function with an `if` aswell, to be sure... `if (mail('bla', $a, $b, $c)) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

add if statement to the mail function :

```
if( mail("myemailaddress@me.com", $subject, $message, $from)) echo "Email sent!";
else echo "failed" ;
```

this way you'll know if it was sent or not .

then start checking the problem .

you man check your php.ini file :

check 
sendmail_from = '';
sendmail_path = '';

and fill them with needed data ... maybe some address doesnt accept emails with no full data in the header . maybe they found it as a spam or somthing else .

Comment: If I change the line `echo "Email sent!";` to that code I get "Warning: mail() expects at least 3 parameters, 0 given in"

Comment: i mean use your function :
if( mail("myemailaddress@me.com", $subject, $message, $from)) .

i updated my reply . check it now please

Comment: It still says email sent to the @me.com email address, I just never receive it.

Comment: ok then you should fill the full headers of the email ... 
eg : 
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

because it may be detected as a spam .

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at your else part where you are using mail .Just below that is the echo so it always get executed as soon as it enters the else block.So, check for mail by if & else condition and then show the massage accordingly